# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 0 ArrayList Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm taking the data from recycler view item by a click, but I have empty ArrayList. I've tried use List, MutableList and still nothing. How to resolve this problem?

```
 private var list: List<City> = ArrayList()


 override fun onCityClick(position: Int) {
    list.get(position).name
    val intent = Intent(this, CityActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
    Log.e("SA onCityClick", list[position].name)
}
```

**The Solution:**
The problem was in my empty list. I didn't pass to empty list and this was the reason of my problem. I'm pasting my solution for this:

```
override fun onCityClick(position: Int) {
    searchViewModel.getAllCities().observe(this, Observer { list ->
        list?.let { cities == list }
        Log.e("SA getAllCities", list[position].name)
        list.get(position)
  })
    val intent = Intent(this, CityActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Sorry for not pasting information about MVVM and Thank you everyone for help.

Comment: well, you need to put something into the list first

Comment: your list is empty but you are trying to access 2nd element

Comment: Yes, I know about it, but I don't know how to resolve this problem. I had same problem in Adapter, but I resolved it by changing ArrayList on List. It does not work in this case.

Comment: bring the part of code where the list gets content . . .

Comment: changing ArrayList to List with list is not gonna fix index out of bound exception . Are you using same list for recyclerview items?

Comment: Of course. In RecyclerView it works.

Comment: @elyarabad You was right. I didn't get content for the list and this is why list was empty.

Comment: don't post the answer on the question itself, edit question to provide the useful info. then post the solution as a separate answer . . .

Answer (score 1):

rather than simple passing the position on click simply pass the name to onCityclick. update your adapter to somehthing like

```
// In main class in you adapter implementation add below code
Adapter(args) { name: String -> //  name :your logic goes here}
```

In adapter class

```
RAdapter(val ..arhs, val listner: onClicklistner ) { 
onBindVIEw { holder.view.clicklistner { listner.event(name) } }
```

this is the rough implementation, i guess this should give you an idea.

this is rough example, share your complete code to help you mode

Comment: I think your solution is pretty simple, but I just pasted solution. Anyway thank you

Answer (score 0):

Replace this,  I hope this will solve your problem

```
override fun onCityClick(position: Int) {
if(list !=null && list.size>position){
list.get(position).name
val intent = Intent(this, CityActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
Log.e("SA onCityClick", list[position].name)
}   
}else{
  Log.e("SA onCityClick", "Size- "+list.size+" -Pos- "+ position)     
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. Log still shows nothing.

Comment: I update my answer now you can view list size and position what you whats to get in logs